# How reliable are smokes?

Tags: rainbow-six-siege

In games such as CS:GO, I believe smoke screens are rendered server-side. This allows for all players in the game to register the exact same smoke screen. (no differences in visibility) In other words, this makes smokes more reliable as you know that as long as your view model is completely shrouded in smoke, the opponent cannot possibly know you are there. (or at least, see any part of you)

However, I am unsure if this is the same for Rainbow Six: Siege. **Are smokes reliable in this case? Are they rendered client or server side?**

Comment: I get the feeling that even in CS:GO, the smoke animations aren't completely server sided.  I get the feeling that the outside edge of the smoke that moves would be a client sided feature.  I can't imagine they would put the effort into syncing those up; and in my experience they don't.  It may be because that part of the smoke isn't fully opaque; so everyone can see through it a bit.  Obviously this doesn't answer your question though; because I don't know if R6S makes the smoke location server sided.

Answer (score 1):

The smokes are indeed reliable and very good after they changed them in an update. Prior to that update the smokes were completely random and client-side so people could see through them while others couldn't. It made for some fairly frustrating moments.

Comment: Welcome to the site, Do you have any links to support your answer? It would be greatly improved if you could provide a source.

Answer (score -1):

I believe they are server side rendered since I tested this.

Comment: How, exactly, did you test that?  We usually need more proof than just your word.

Comment: By taking my friends pc (the same pc as mine (same graphics)) and getting into a casual game not custom. We looked at the smoke at different angles with each PC. It was the same...

Comment: That sounds like a good thing to edit into your answer.